# Calling C++ from java with JNI standalone methods

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna, jnativehook

i need to use C++ methods from java with a compiled DLL **that doesn't include the JNI Export functions**. I need my DLL to be used from Java using JNA or JNI. JNA was easy to do using an interface but how can i achieve the same thing with JNI? Is it possible to run the .cpp file with the export functions on his own standalone thing? Thanks

Comment: You need to write another DLL that calls this DLL, and that exports JNI native methods.

Comment: Yeah this is what i thought, no way of passing around that?

Comment: There is no way around it.

Comment: My dll will have to receive a class from the other dll in order to export the JNI native methods?